# Custom inheritance JsonConverter fails when JsonConverterAttribute is used

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize derived type, and I want to use a custom property `Type` to distinguish between derived types.

```
[
  {
    "Type": "a",
    "Height": 100
  },
  {
    "Type": "b",
    "Name": "Joe"
  }
]
```

The solution I came to was to create a custom `JsonConverter`. On `ReadJson` I read the `Type` property and instantiate that type through the `ToObject<T>` function. Everything works fine until I use a `JsonConverterAttribute`. The `ReadJson` method loops infinitely because the attribute is applied on subtypes too.

How do I prevent this attribute from being applied to the subtypes?

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TypeSerializer))]
public abstract class Base
{
    private readonly string type;

    public Base(string type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public string Type { get { return type; } }
}

public class AType : Base
{
    private readonly int height;

    public AType(int height)
        : base("a")
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int Height { get { return height; } }
}

public class BType : Base
{
    private readonly string name;

    public BType(string name)
        : base("b")
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return name; } }
}

public class TypeSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Base);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var j = JObject.Load(reader);

        var type = j["Type"].ToObject<string>();

        if (type == "a")
            // Infinite Loop! StackOverflowException
            return j.ToObject<AType>(); 
        if (type == "b")
            return j.ToObject<BType>();

        throw new NotImplementedException(type);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class InheritanceSerializeTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Deserialize()
    {
        var json = @"{""Type"":""a"", ""Height"":100}";
        JObject.Parse(json).ToObject<Base>(); // Crash
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar problem with a project that I am currently working on: I wanted to make a custom `JsonConverter` and map it to my entities via attributes, but then the code got trapped in an infinite loop.

What did the trick in my case was using `serializer.Populate` instead of `JObject.ToObject` (I couldn't use `.ToObject` even if I wanted to; I am using version 3.5.8, in which this function does not exist). Below is my `ReadJson` method as an example:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JContainer lJContainer = default(JContainer);

    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        lJContainer = JObject.Load(reader);
        existingValue = Convert.ChangeType(existingValue, objectType);
        existingValue = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        serializer.Populate(lJContainer.CreateReader(), existingValue);
    }

    return existingValue;
}
```

Comment: Even if it is an old answer, it still does the trick on NewtonSoft 10 ;) The problem is still present. And I couldn't find any other solutions.

Comment: This one is great, the most decent simple solution I have found.

Comment: tbh I don't remember, it's been a long time. Right now it seems to have no point at all since `Activator.CreateInstance` will return a new instance of the `objectType` with all default values, effectively making the `Convert.ChangeType` line useless.

Comment: There is one flaw in this response as objectType would be the base type wouldnt it?

Comment: as far as I remember it's the type that you specified on the `Deserialize<T>` call.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `[JsonConverter(typeof(TypeSerializer))]` attribute from the `Base` class and in the `Deserialize` test replace the following line:

```
JObject.Parse(json).ToObject<Base>(); // Crash
```

with this one:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(json, new TypeSerializer());
```

**UPDATE 1** This update matches the comment from the asker of the question:

Leave the `[JsonConverter(typeof(TypeSerializer))]` attribute to the `Base` class. Use the following line for deserialization:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(json);
```

and modify the `ReadJson` method like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var j = JObject.Load(reader);

    if (j["Type"].ToString() == "a")
        return new AType(int.Parse(j["Height"].ToString()));

    return new BType(j["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine, but I want to use the attribute. The attribute is more convenient, it's declared once over the type, no need to search for the serializer every time.

Comment: Not really Ilija. You see, I have a lot of objects actually with heavy constructors because of immutable types I use. And I like how Json.NET creates these types using these constructors. But as I understand, I cannot use this default instantiator without getting into this infinite loop... It seems I have to create my custom solution for this or just use the DeserializeObject<Base>(json, new TypeSerializer())

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to this and encountered the infinite loop.

The Api I was consuming could return an error response or the expected type.
I got around the problem in the same way as others have highlighted with using serializer.Populate.

```
public class Error{
   public string error_code { get; set; }
   public string message { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter<Success>))]
public class Success{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class CustomConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : new() {
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
      if (jObject.ContainsKey("error_code")) {
          return jObject.ToObject(typeof(ProvisoErrorResponse));
      }

      var instance = new T();
      serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), instance);
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Then used by HttpClient like this:

```
using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
{
   return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Success>();
}
```

Why does this loop occur? I think we're assuming a fallacy.
I initially tried calling base.ReadJson thinking that I was overriding existing functionality when in fact there are many JsonConverters and our custom converter isnt overriding anything as the base class has no real methods. It would be better to treat the base class like an interface instead.
The loop occurs because the converter registered by us is the converter that the engine considers most applicable to the type to be converted. Unless we can remove our own converter from the converter list at runtime, calling on the engine to deserialize while within our custom converter will create infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

JsonConverters are inherited from base classes.  There currently is no option to limit the JsonConverter to only a base class.  You can overwrite it though.

Tested on Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3

```
public class DisabledConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

Then overwrite the JsonConverter on the derived classes.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DisabledConverter))]
public class AType : Base
...

[JsonConverter(typeof(DisabledConverter))]
public class BType : Base
...
```

**Details**

This only applies to the code:

```
if (type == "a")
    return j.ToObject<AType>(); 
if (type == "b")
    return j.ToObject<BType>();
```

When calling .ToObject it will try to use the converter (again) defined on the base class to deserialize to the object.  This is what makes an infinite loop.

You need to override the JsonConverter on the derived class.

The CanRead => false and CanWrite => false will disable the custom JsonConverter for that class forcing the .ToObject call to use the default logic internally inside Newtonsoft.Json instead of your TypeSerializer class.